# Executing spark sql in aws glue returns the column name in the queries rather than values

Tags: apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog, aws-glue-spark

running spark sql in aws glue returns the column name in the queries

```
data:

product,price,quantityinKG

mango,100,1

apple,200,3

peach,200,2

mango,200,2
```

My Test Query

```
         eg : select product,sum(price)

              from myDataSource

              group by product
```

The output of the query should be

```
            product, sum(price)

            mango, 300
```

but output is :

```
            product, "sum(price)"

            mango,
```

There is nothing in the sum(price) column it only has the  product nane , please can you help me with this behaviour of glue

Comment: How did you get this data? What type of source was it? If using a crawler perhaps the column names were grabbed as part of the data, which can happen if your settings don't align to your source data file.

Comment: I crawled the data from s3 bucket actually using a glue crawler. have you worked with AWS GLUE

Comment: I'm very familiar with glue. What type of data are you crawling? CSV? Can you provide some example data? Are you using a classifier on your crawler? If so, what are the settings on it?

Comment: @jonlegend  I have mentioned the dataset in the first line of my question. Yes I am using an inbuilt csv classifier.  I didn't get the last part . what are the setting on ? Please can you elaborate the last part

Comment: Does your data have "data:" as the first line as in the code block above?

Comment: @jonlegend  it starts from " product,price,quantityinKG" that's the first the line , Thanks so much for helping

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create or replace a local temporary view with your dataframe and then use the sql query

```
data.createOrReplaceTempView('data_table')
spark.sql("select product, sum(price) as sum_price from data_table group by product").show()
```

If you are using the glue dynamic dataframe, then first convert it into a spark dataframe using toDF() function before creating the temp view.

Comment: Its actually an AWS GLUE problem , have you worked with GLUE or is it s general answer related to spark?

Comment: I work on AWS Glue, do you think GLUE has a different process to execute the spark sql?

Comment: Apologies , I didn't mean to question your expertise , I feel its more of crawler things , that's what I am guessing. let me paste me script     """" def sparkSqlQuery(glueContext, query, mapping, transformation_ctx) -> DynamicFrame:
    for alias, frame in mapping.items():
        frame.toDF().createOrReplaceTempView(alias)
    result = spark.sql(query)
    return DynamicFrame.fromDF(result, glueContext, transformation_ctx)

SqlQuery0 = '''
select product,sum(price) as total
from myDataSource
group by product
'''

Comment: I actually wrote the script in glue studio as it has a sparkSQL tab where you can only enter sparkSQL code not scripts nothing.

Comment: it starts from " product,price,quantityinKG" that's the first the line , Thanks so much for helping

Comment: If you think it's a crawler issue I would suggest executing the same query in Athena.

Comment: by running the query in the Athena you can verify whether your crawler crawled the data properly

Comment: Thanks I think why its a crawler issue because the Data was read by it only and that was the only previous step involved.ok ill try to do that . thanks a lot . Will post of there is some more issue.

Comment: can you please help me out with this glue issue? Its a diff issue where we write our custom script.